# r-cran-packages on ubuntu repos

Tags: r, ubuntu

usually I install R packages from CRAN mirrors, but some of them give me problems. This almost always happens with packages strongly interacting with the system (e.g. rgl, cairoDevices etc). If I well understood when I install packages from the Ubuntu repo with

```
apt-get install r-cran-rgl
```

these will be installed in `/usr/lib/R/site-library` directory. For a number of packages installed in `/usr/lib/R/site-library`  when I do `update.packages(ask=FALSE)` from R (working under sys admin) I get the following type of messages:

```
Warning: package 'ggplot2' in library '/usr/lib/R/site-library' will not be updated
```

I presume that this happens because the version on the cran is newer than the one on the ubuntu repos. But, the rgl package is installed 
in '/usr/lib/R/site-library', however when I invoke

```
update.packages(ask=FALSE)
```

R download and tries to install a new version of rgl although the one installed is the last one available on ubuntu repos. By the way it tries to install and it fails for some error.

Therefore, what I don't understand is why it doesn't try to update ggplot2 while it tries to update rgl when both have been installed via apt-get and both have the last release number appearing on the ubuntu repos.

Thanks
Pierre

Comment: I answered all this several times here over the years, try some searches such as `[r] ubuntu debian /usr/local/lib/R /usr/lib/R`.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, i did the search you suggested and I finally got to this ``https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/#debian-sid-unstable``. If I well understood to solve the problem I could set the debian unstable repo with ``deb http://<favourite-cran-mirror>/bin/linux/debian sid/`` and then update via apt-get. The question is: since I work with Ubuntu 14.04 Lts, could this cause instabilities to the system when I install something that needs system dependencies? Thanks in advance, Pierre